# How to find unique entries in an array

Tags: arrays, matrix, unique

I have a program that scans a large number of n by n matrices for rotations and mirror images. The output is a linear array that represents a flattened out lower triangular matrix with zeros and ones depending whether or not the respective matrices are in fact rotations/mirrors of each other.
Given 6 matrices to check the program only checks the "necessary" matrices and does not check them twice. If it is a rotation/mirror it sets that element to one. An example is shown below.

```
   0   1   2   3   4
1  0
2  0   1 
3  1   0   0
4  1   0   0   1
5  1   0   0   1   1
```

The output would look like this:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

By looking at this we can see that there are two unique matrices (0 & 1). The rest are duplicates (3, 4, 5 are duplicates of 0; 2 is a duplicate of 1).
How can i find 1) the number of unique matrices from that linear output and 2) a new set only with unique matrices sorted with the lowest indices.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is way simpler than I expected. One can find the number of unique entries by looping through all columns and marking which entries are duplicates. If the end of the column is reached the counter is incremented. All marked columns are skipped all together. At the end the last entry is checked and the counter incremented if it is one.